# The non-generic method 'HttpClient.GetAsync(string)' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: blazor

I have this code which register `HttpClient`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client =>
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx/"));
    }
```

and to use it, I injected it at my Blazor razor page,

```
@page "/Movies/FetchMovies"
@inject IHttpClientFactory http;
@using System.Text.Json

<MovieList Movies="movies" />

@code{
    private List<Movie> movies;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var client = http.CreateClient("ServerAPI");        
        movies = await client.GetAsync<List<Movie>>("api/Movies");

        //movies = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Movie>>("api/Movies");
    }
}
```

Problem is this line `movies = await client.GetAsync<List<Movie>>("api/Movies");` gets an error:
`The non-generic method 'HttpClient.GetAsync(string)' cannot be used with type arguments`

I tried with `movies = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Movie>>("api/Movies")` but also get an error.

Comment: as the error says, HttpClient.GetAsync(string) is not a generic method, `GetAsync<T>(string)` is not possible.

Comment: Agree with jps - GetAsync on HttpClient doesn't have any generic overloads. so that error makes sense. And for the GetFromJsonAsync method - what is the error? I wonder if you're missing a reference to System.Net.Http.Json?

Comment: use it like this: `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(...)`

Comment: "GetFromJsonAsync ... also get an error" : which error? Always post error messages. And that is the correct function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that like this:

```
@code{
    private List<Movie> movies;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var client = http.CreateClient("ServerAPI");        
        var response= await client.GetAsync("api/Movies");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();


        movies = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Movie>> 
                      (responseContent,
             new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use the `GetFromJsonAsync` method instead, do the following:

1. Install the package `System.Net.Http.Json`
2. reference the namespaces: `System.Text.Json` and `System.Net.Http.Json`

either to your specific razor file, or to the /_Imports.razor file.

Now this code will the job...

```
movies = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Movie>>("api/Movies");
```

Comment: Odd. It's there a repo online I can look at?